# Extracting text around specific word from PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am basic level python user and I am trying to create a program that gives the text before and after (like 50 words before and 50 words after) a specific word that I use. So far I managed to create a program that gives which page of PDF is word mentioned. How can I write into CVS these additional 100 words?

```
import PyPDF2
import re
import os
...
for pdfName in pdffiles:
    pdfFull = pdfFolder + pdfName
    pdfFileObj = open(pdfFull, mode='rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

    number_of_pages = pdfReader.numPages
    pages_text = []
    words_start_pos = {}
    words = {}

    csvFolder = newpath
    csvName = pdfName.replace('pdf', 'csv')
    csvFull = csvFolder + csvName
    with open(csvFull, 'w') as f:
        f.write('{0},{1},{2}\n'.format("Sheet Number", "Search Word", "File Name"))
        for word in searchwords:
            for page in range(number_of_pages):
                pages_text.append(pdfReader.getPage(page).extractText())
                words_start_pos[page] = [dwg.start() for dwg in re.finditer(word, pages_text[page].lower())]
                words[page] = [pages_text[page][value:value + len(word)] for value in words_start_pos[page]]
            for page in words:
                for i in range(0, len(words[page])):
                    if str(words[page][i]) != 'nan':
                        f.write('{0},{1},{2}\n'.format(page + 1, words[page][i], pdfFull))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is necessary to grab every letter of the page and to find the index of the first letter, instead you can still do the:

```
pages_text.append(pdfReader.getPage(page).extractText())
```

and then do something like this:

```
pages_text[0].split()
```

which will get you each word from the extracted text so instead of indexing letters and having to figure out where words start and end, you already have the words. At this point I would iterate over the words and find the index of the word and then add and subtract 50 from that word's position and print them out. I used it on the first page of a pdf as follows:

```
import PyPDF2
import re
import os


pdfFileObj = open(r'C:\path','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

number_of_pages = pdfReader.numPages
pages_text = []
words_start_pos = {}
words = {}
searchwords = ["pdf"]
word_pos = 0
print_words = []


word_pos = []
print_text = ''
line = []

for word in searchwords:
    for page in range(number_of_pages):
        pages_text.append(pdfReader.getPage(page).extractText())

text = pages_text[0].split()
for each_word in range(0, len(text)):
    if(text[each_word] == "PDF"):
        word_pos.append(each_word)

print(word_pos)
for each_pos in word_pos:    
    for each_word in range(each_pos-50, each_pos+50):
        print_text = print_text +' ' + text[each_word]
    line.append(print_text)
    print_text = ''    
print(line)
with open(r'C:\path', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{0},{1},{2}\n'.format("Sheet Number", word, "File Name"))
    for each_line in line:
        f.write('{0},{1},{2}\n'.format(page + 1, each_line, r'C:\path'))
```

Note: I would be wary of saving text grabbed from a pdf in a csv file because there could very well be commas in the text which would mess with your csv file. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help but I wasn't able to make it work. Can I send the code as a whole so you can show exactly where I need to change? I am really new to this. If you give me an email address or something. 

Thanks anyway. 
Okan

Comment: @OkanAydogdu I changed it to the whole program that I can run on my machine. I stripped out some of your logic so you'll have to add some of that back in. I hope it helps